# GoProxy SSL interception in golang

Tags: ssl, https, go, proxy

I am trying to block requests to anything over HTTPS

It works perfectly for HTTP, however HTTPS seems able to completely avoid my proxy. I am using foxyproxy in firefox to set it to use my proxy.

The following code will print the URL when the request from the browser requests over HTTP, but over HTTPS I see nothing.

Any ideas why??

```
func DropHTTPS() net.Listener {
    listener, _ = net.Listen(CONN_TYPE, CONN_HOST+":"+CONN_PORT)
    proxy := goproxy.NewProxyHttpServer()
    proxy.OnRequest().DoFunc(func (req *http.Request, ctx *goproxy.ProxyCtx) (*http.Request, *http.Response) {
        log.Println("url: ", req.URL)
        return req, nil
    })
    go http.Serve(listener, proxy)
    return listener
}
```

EDIT: 
I just read about `HTTPS CONNECT` and perhaps that is how I need to handle the fact that an HTTPS request is made.
The goproxy library seems to have `HTTPSHandler()` and `HijackConnect()` available, although I don't want to MITM the connection, I just want to block it.

EDIT AGAIN:
This code, seems to run the HTTPS proxy on a different port to HTTP. Im not sure if this needs to be configured in Firefox, or my proxy can just listen on one port for both HTTP and HTTPS.

Also, do I need to 'listen' differently?

`HandleConnectFunc()` or something?

Comment: You can't listen to http and http on the same port, they're different protocols. They are also 2 different proxy settings, because you need to MITM https in order to proxy it. If you want to block https, do it at the firewall, or set the https proxy to a closed port.

Comment: If you set an HTTPS proxy in your browser, it will connect to the proxy over HTTP, and use a CONNECT request. If you're running a transparent proxy, HTTPS needs to be listening on a separate port from HTTP so that it's ready to accept encrypted connections.

Comment: I want to kill the CONNECT and respond with a HTTP/HTML page stating that secure connections are denied through this proxy. This catches the CONNECT, but I don't know how to respond with a custom response:
```
  proxy.OnRequest().HandleConnectFunc(func(host string, ctx *goproxy.ProxyCtx) (*goproxy.ConnectAction, string) {
   log.Println("connecting: ", ctx.Req.URL.Host)
  return goproxy.OkConnect, host
 })
```

Comment: @amlwwalker did you solve this problem ?

Comment: I did! If u check my github for projects I have contributed to, and see Mustard, I've got it working in there. When I'm by computer can link to it, otherwise ask me questions using the issues in github

Comment: @amlwwalker done, I added an issue

Comment: Responded on github